# SKAction forces nodes through each other after collision

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode, skaction

This issue has been [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719413/does-spritekit-apply-physics-if-i-modify-the-position-and-rotation-of-a-sksprite) somewhat, but I would like to hear other people experience with physics world forcing nodes to pass through each other unpredictably.

I am using a SKAction to move one node. This node needs to slide at constant speed through the scene until it reaches a certain position. A 2nd node is falling through gravity until it touches the scene frame.

When the two nodes collide, I would assume the falling node is lifted against the gravity. Instead, occasionally, the 2nd node is repositioned on the opposite side of the first node. The collision is properly detected in the didBeginContact.

This seems to depend on the speed of the SKAction. If I slow down the SKAction that makes the 1st node slide by as little as 20%, the collision lift the 2nd node as expected.

What is the best way to work around this kind of behaviors?

Comment: >I am using a SKAction to move one node.  How!?  Show us how you do it.  Or are you just looking for a solution in words?

Comment: I am using the following SKAction to scroll a container node vertically at constant speed:  SKAction *scrollVerticalAction = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:verticalScroll duration:duration];  If I cannot combine SKActions with physics, can I change the container node velocity? My container node definition is as follow:  containerNode = [[SKNode alloc] init];
    containerNode.name = @"obstaclesContainerNode";
    [self addChild: containerNode];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is pretty much explained in that link. If you are interested in physics simulation the only sanctioned way is to move all bodies through physics by applying forces or impulses, or by directly changing velocity vector.

If you look how each frame is processed in SpriteKit, you will se that :

- actions are executed first
- physics is simulated after

So, if you move a node manually, you are not letting the physics simulation to move it where it thinks it should be appropriate. You are pulling the object out of sync with an actual physics simulation. Also, this way, the node will be moved by both - the action and the physics engine, thus the unexpected result.

Contact detection will work though. But don't confuse terms "contact" and "collision" . Contacts will be trigered properly even if you use SKActions to move bodies. But, collisions may not be properly simulated etc . So as long as you are interested in contacts, you are good to go. If interested in any kind of physics similation, then use appropriate ways to interact with physics world.